# Compiling a C program

Tags: c, compiler-construction

i am trying to compile this code, but if i do using:

```
gcc prt.c portaudio.h -o prt
```

but i get this error:

```
main.c:47: undefined reference to `Pa_OpenDefaultStream'
main.c:62: undefined reference to `Pa_StartStream'
main.c:65: undefined reference to `Pa_Sleep'
main.c:66: undefined reference to `Pa_StopStream'
main.c:69: undefined reference to `Pa_CloseStream'
main.c:72: undefined reference to `Pa_Terminate'
main.c:78: undefined reference to `Pa_Terminate'
```

i don't know why, then i though it might be beacuse i don't have a rule (make file)
so i made one:

```
main: main.o
    gcc main.o -o main

main.o: main.c portaudio.h
    gcc -c main.c
```

but when i try to run it through cygwin: using "Make"
i get this message:

```
"make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.
```

I don't understand the problem, please help me is something wrong with my makefile or is there something else wrong.

also this is the code:
main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "portaudio.h"

#define SAMPLE_RATE (44100)


typedef struct
{
   float left_phase;
   float right_phase;
}
paTestData;

static int patestCallback( const void *inputBuffer, void *outputBuffer,
                       unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
                       const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
                       PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
                       void *userData )
{
/* Cast data passed through stream to our structure. */
paTestData *data = (paTestData*)userData;
float *out = (float*)outputBuffer;
unsigned int i;
(void) inputBuffer; /* Prevent unused variable warning. */

for( i=0; i<framesPerBuffer; i++ )
{
    *out++ = data->left_phase;  /* left */
    *out++ = data->right_phase;  /* right */
    /* Generate simple sawtooth phaser that ranges between -1.0 and 1.0. */
    data->left_phase += 0.01f;
    /* When signal reaches top, drop back down. */
    if( data->left_phase >= 1.0f ) data->left_phase -= 2.0f;
    /* higher pitch so we can distinguish left and right. */
    data->right_phase += 0.03f;
    if( data->right_phase >= 1.0f ) data->right_phase -= 2.0f;
}
return 0;
}


static paTestData data;

int main (void) {
PaStream *stream;
PaError err;
err = Pa_OpenDefaultStream( &stream,
                            0,          /* no input channels */
                            2,          /* stereo output */
                            paFloat32,  /* 32 bit floating point output */
                            SAMPLE_RATE,
                            256,        /* frames per buffer, i.e. the number
                                               of sample frames that PortAudio will
                                               request from the callback. Many apps
                                               may want to use
                                               paFramesPerBufferUnspecified, which
                                               tells PortAudio to pick the best,
                                               possibly changing, buffer size.*/
                            patestCallback, /* this is your callback function */
                            &data ); /*This is a pointer that will be passed to
                                               your callback*/
                         err = Pa_StartStream( stream );
                         if( err != paNoError ) goto error;

                         Pa_Sleep(9*1000);
                        err = Pa_StopStream( stream );
                        if( err != paNoError ) goto error;

                        err = Pa_CloseStream( stream );
                        if( err != paNoError ) goto error;

                        err = Pa_Terminate( );
                        if( err != paNoError ) goto error;

                        printf("Test finished.\n");
                        return err;
                    error:
                        Pa_Terminate();

                        return err;




   }
```

and the header file portaudio.h: [Portaudio.h](http://pastebin.com/ZTeAyuJU)
if you want cleaner view of main.c: [main.c](http://pastebin.com/PEW01SVi)

I am not so sure why these messages/errors/warning are coming, please help.

also this is my folder view:
[image]

Comment: where are the symbols Pa_* defined? Is there a library that you should be linking against?

Comment: yes there is a lib called portaudio_x86.lib, but i don't know how to link that in the make file or where to put it.

also if you know how to do it in visual C++ 2008, it would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using functions from a library for the 'Port Audio' facility, but your link line does not tell the C compiler how to find that library - so the functions show up as undefined references.

Your link line should look something like:

```
gcc -o main main.o -lpa
```

That should be macroized, but the gist is correct.

This assumes the library is in 'libpa.a' or thereabouts.  If it is in 'libportaudio.so', then use `-lportaudio` instead of `-lpa`.

Using macros in the makefile:

```
PROGRAM = main
SOURCE  = main.c
OBJECT  = $(SOURCE:.c=.o)
LIBDIR  = /cygdrive/c/installdir/portaudio/lib
LIBRARY = $(LIBDIR)/portaudio_x86.lib

$(PROGRAM): $(OBJECT)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJECT) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBRARY)


main.o: main.c portaudio.h
```

You should not need an explicit compilation command for `main.o`; `make` should be able to deduce that from its internal rules.   Note that the character before `$(CC)` must be a <kbd>TAB</kbd> and not spaces.

Comment: it came with "portaudio_x86.lib" so i would add:
 gcc -o main main.o -portaudio_x86
but where would i add this in the make file?

Comment: @Rave: I'm not sure whether you can use the `-lxyz` notation with libraries when the name is not of the form `libxyz.lib`.  Specifying the full path to the library, as shown in the makefile example, should work.

Comment: hey i did that:
http://pastebin.com/sCtC3WBm
but i still get this error:
"make: *** No rule to make target 'main.c', needed by 'main.o'. Stop."

Answer (score 1):

The `make` command only looks for a file called `makefile` or `Makefile`, to use make with a differently named makefile, you need to do `make -f otherfile target`.

Rename your file `Make` file to `Makefile` to have make look at its contents.  Also, verify that you use one tab character (no spaces) in all of the commands under a target.  You might have done that, but your cut-and-paste of the contents in this posting doesn't let us know if that is really how it is.

Comment: Hey, i did that, now i get another error/warning.
make: *** No rule to make target 'main.c', needed by 'main.o'. Stop.
this doesn't make sense. (and i do have one tab, for target )

Comment: It doesn't know how to make `main.c` which usually means that there is no main.c in that directory.  Check for file permissions issues and that there are no differences in upper/lower case.  If you see a `main.c` and can't figure out what else it might be, then odds are you have a special character embedded into the file name.  If so, copying it to `main.c` would work.

Comment: hey, just to follow up (in case someone might have the same problem), i used netbeans (or you can use Visual C++) and i made a project, added source and header file. One thing i forgot was to link it, so go to project properties->Link and add the linker file there.

Just in case someone searches on google who has the same problem

Answer (score 1):

It would also appear that you need the PortAudio library to link to or those functions will not be defined. That is, unless they're defined in the header (I haven't used that library before...)

Answer (score 1):

Did portaudio come with a .lib or anything? The header file only contains the name of the functions, not the definitions. You'll need to link against the library to get the functionality for all of those functions

Answer (score 1):

Your initial problem ("Undefined reference to...") is a message from the **linker** saying it cannot find a definition of the functions mentioned. This means you need to add a linker argument saying that you want to add the library providing these functions (lib portaudio?) to your program. GCC's command line parameter to do so is "-l"

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need to include the library (with a `-l[library name]` option.
A search of portaudio compile commands shows `libportaudio.a` included in the gcc options.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably not linking to those libraries libs (.so or .a) look at the documentation and see what libs you need to link your program with.

The other thing is that when you run "make -f Makefile" you need to have a tab in your makefile before the "gcc..." lines i.e. the command lines.

Answer (score 0):

I also need to add `-lm`, otherwise it throws an error.
So `gcc -o test test.c -lm -lportaudio`